# Kornshell (ksh) listing/sorting files

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, ksh

How would I sort files by modification time (most recent at the top) and only have one column?

I tried:

```
    ls -1 | ls -lt
```

and

```
    ls -lt | -1
```

but the first has extraneous columns, and the second lists them in one column, but in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls "filepath" -t -1
```

this will sort the date last modified and print out 1 row at a time.

I don't think you can do both with piping unless you want to have it list twice.